# Value from addEventListeners e.traget

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to store a value as id from EventListener? I need an ID from this list when I click on item.

This is what I've tried:

```html
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="item-list" id="1"></li>
      <li class="item-list" id="2"></li>
      <li class="item-list" id="3"></li>
    </ul>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        list.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            let podlistIndex;
            if (e.target.classList.contains("item-list")) {
                podlistIndex= e.target.getAttribute("id");
            }
    
            console.log(podlistIndex);
        });
    </script>
```

When the item is clicked, I can get value as an id, but the value is lost when I click somewhere else. How can I store the value?

Comment: Store The ID in a global variable, instead of a local one.....(declare before the event listener)  even in this case the value will be lost after clicking somewhere... I suggest using a array instead and use `array.push()` method instead

Comment: There are many ways to approach this, but it all depends on _how_ you intend to use `podlistIndex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the variable outside the event handler

```js
let podlistIndex;
list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   if (e.target.classList.contains("item-list")) {
      podlistIndex = e.target.getAttribute("id");
   }

   console.log(podlistIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array outside the function and fill it up every single click you make. This way it won't overwrite any id.

```
<script>
const ids = [];
let list = document.querySelector('.list');
list.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
   let podlistIndex;

       if (e.target.classList.contains("item-list")) {
        podlistIndex= e.target.getAttribute("id");
        ids.push(podlistIndex);
      }

   console.log(ids);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: The solution is good, thanks!